# FullCalendar Asp.Net WebForms

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement [FullCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmhGx.png) on my ASP.NET **WebForms** Project. I've seen some examples to achieve this without any luck since they're for MVC which I'm not used to.

My **Events** Database Table:

```
EventId (int)
Subject (nvarchar (100))
Description (nvarchar (300))
Start (datetime)
End (datetime)
ThemeColor ((nvarchar (10))
IsFullDay (bit)
```

**WebForm2.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="calendar">
        </div>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p id="pDetails"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var events = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetEvents",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                title: v.Subject,
                                description: v.Description,
                                start: moment(v.Start),
                                end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                                color: v.ThemeColor,
                                allDay: v.IsFullDay
                            });
                        })

                        GenerateCalendar(events);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                    //error: function (error) {
                    //    alert('failed');
                    //}
                })

                function GenerateCalendar(events) {
                    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        contentHeight: 400,
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                        },
                        eventLimit: true,
                        eventColor: '#378006',
                        events: events,
                        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                            $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                            var $description = $('<div/>');
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                            if (calEvent.end != null) {
                                $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                            }
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                            $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                            $('#myModal').modal();
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm2.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        //[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static List<events> GetEvents()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetEvents", sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                    ad.Fill(dt);
                    sqlConn.Close();
                }
            }

            return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(datarow =>
            new events()
            {
                EventId = Convert.ToInt32(datarow["EventId]),
                Subject = Convert.ToString(datarow["Subject"]),
                Description = Convert.ToString(datarow["Description"]),
                Start = Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["Start"]),
                End = Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["End"]),
                ThemeColor = Convert.ToString(datarow["ThemeColor"]),
                IsFullDay = false
            }
            ).ToList();
        }

        public class events
        {
            public int EventId { get; set; }
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime Start { get; set; }
            public DateTime End { get; set; }
            public string ThemeColor { get; set; }
            public bool IsFullDay { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code, the events are loaded from the Database (i've put a breakpoint on it) but not populated into the Calendar. The Calendar does show but without the events. Can someone help me out with this?

---

[image: Array1]

[image: Array2]

Here are couple of images

Comment: What does your `events` array show when you call `GenerateCalendar(events);`?

Comment: Webmethods, for reasons unknown, generally place the data you return into a subproperty "d" of the generated JSON object. So you'll probably be wanting to do `$.each(data.d, function (i, v) {`. Hopefully that should sort it. P.S. You can easily inspect the JSON you get back by watching your browser's Network tools to see the AJAX request going to your WebMethod, and then clicking on it, and going to the Response tab. That would give you the clue that the returned data structure wasn't quite what you expected.

Comment: <code>$.each(data.d, function (i, v) {</code>

this solved my problem. Thanks alot for the help ADyson.