# Full Calendar not displaying on web form; script not running

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, fullcalendar

I have tried to create a full calendar on my web page using Visual Studio.  However, as I execute my codes, the full calendar did not show up. I have taken reference for my codes from [FullCalendar Asp.Net WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590383/fullcalendar-asp-net-webforms).

**Student_Schedule.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id ="calendar"></div>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p id="pDetails"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var events= [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Student_Schedule.aspx/GetEvents",
                    sucess: function (data) {
                        $.each(data.d, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                title: v.BookingStatus,
                                description: v.PilotName,
                                start: moment(v.BookingTime),
                                end: v.BookingTimeEnd != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                            });
                        })
                        GenerateCalendar(events);
                    },

                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                })

                function GenerateCalendar(events) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        contentHeight: 400,
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        timeFormat: 'h:mm',
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev, next, today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay, agenda'
                        },
                        eventLimit: true,
                        eventColor: '#ooCED1',
                        events: events,

                        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                            $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                            var $description = $('<div/>');
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")));
                            if (calEvent.end != null) {
                                $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")));
                            }
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                            $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                            $('#myModal').modal();

                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Student_Schedule.aspx.cs**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<Bookings> GetEvents()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetBookings", sqlConn))
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlConn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                ad.Fill(dt);
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }

        return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(datarow => new Bookings()

        {
            BookingId = Convert.ToInt32(datarow["BookingId"]),
            StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(datarow["StudentId"]),
            PilotName = Convert.ToString(datarow["PilotName"]),
            StudentName = Convert.ToString(datarow["StudentName"]),
            BookingTime = Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["BookingTime"]),
            BookingTimeEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["BookingTimeEnd"]),
            BookingStatus = Convert.ToString(datarow["BookingStatus"])
        }).ToList();
    }

    public class Bookings
    {
        public int BookingId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string PilotName { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BookingTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime BookingTimeEnd { get; set; }
        public string BookingStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

[GetEvents Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnAlE.png)

[GetEvents Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQZLj.png)

Comment: if you want to debug Javascript, you must manually set a breakpoint in Chrome/Firefox/Edge, or you type debugger; in your code, at your breakpoint location. It's very usefull!

Comment: `<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>` ...you are including jQuery twice - this is not needed, and it can also lead to unexpected problems. Pick either the .js version (if you want to be able to debug issues within jQuery) or the .min.js version (if you just want to use it efficiently) and include only one of them

Comment: As for your debugger error...you seem to be trying to debug Javascript code using the Visual Studio debugger....normally that debugger will only debug the server-side C# and aspx code. Unless you have specifically set it up, then it won't debug JavaScript. But anyway it's likely to be easier to debug the Javascript using your browser's built-in Developer Tools which contains a JS debugger and lots of other useful tools - like the Console to see JS errors, and the Network area to debug AJAX calls.

Comment: So if you're having problems with the calendar showing up, this is likely to be because of JavaScript issues. Please remove one copy of jQuery as I suggested above. if that doesn't help, then open your Developer Tools (press F12 in most browsers) and go to the Console and see if any other errors are shown there, and tell us what you see.

Comment: Hi, I have already removed one of the jQuery. But the same issue persists, I have edited my above post on the error that was shown on Console.

Comment: That error is just because you didn't load a favicon.ico file (to create an icon for your page in the browser's tab list). It has nothing to do with fullCalendar or anything else relevant.

Comment: So next, please open the Network tab, and then reload your page. Check if you can see any request going to `Student_Schedule.aspx/GetEvents` or not. Then if you can, click on that request to open it up, and see what response you are getting from the server. Your calendar will only show up if that request succeeds

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding me. I have just edited my post regarding the response. I think the problem might lies in my stored procedure as I am new to understanding and writing a stored procedure. Could you perhaps give me an example prior to my case on how to write for the stored procedure?

Comment: what makes you think there's a problem with your stored procedure (not that I can see the code for that, I can only see the code which calls it)? The response you are getting from GetEvents looks fine to me. Just one thing I couldn't see from the screenshot, does it return a "200 OK" status? And are there any more errors shown in the console after that happens? And can you please write `console.log(JSON.stringify(events));` just before the line `GenerateCalendar(events);` in your Javascript, so we can see what the final event list being sent to fullCalendar looks like?

Comment: Actually, forget all that, I just noticed...you have a typo: `sucess:` in the $.ajax options needs to be `success:` ! Otherwise jQuery will not recognise it, and will not execute anything when the response is received. It will just ignore it. Change that and I'm pretty confident it will work. Always double-check your work, in programming the smallest details are important! (Also, learn to use the JS debugger in your browser, it would have shown you hopefully that the success code was never being executed, which would have given you a clue without having to proof-read the code).

Comment: Thanks for your help, you have made me learnt how to use JS debugger in my browser. The calendar has finally displayed out.